# Failed to include Retrofit version > 2.6 in Project

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I try to include Retrofit with Gson converter in my project.
Without the changes in the gradle file, everything works. When I add the dependencies

```
 implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
 implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
 implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

to my gradle file, the project still compiles and even installs the app, but it crashes with this error:

```
2020-07-10 21:14:02.261 9083-9083/com.testproject.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.testproject.app, PID: 9083
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.testproject.app/com.testproject.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.testproject.app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.testproject.app-Au1uLD6rtjGrZa2PoCEKZA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.testproject.app-Au1uLD6rtjGrZa2PoCEKZA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.testproject.app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.testproject.app-Au1uLD6rtjGrZa2PoCEKZA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.testproject.app-Au1uLD6rtjGrZa2PoCEKZA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.testproject.app-Au1uLD6rtjGrZa2PoCEKZA==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.testproject.app-Au1uLD6rtjGrZa2PoCEKZA==/base.apk': Bad method handle type 7
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:676)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:709)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:936)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2242)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5672)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
                ... 6 more
```

**Edit:**

Found out that it works with Retrofit 2.6.0, but not with greater versions.

Answer (score 1):

You only need the Square GSON dependency - remove the GSON dependency from Google. Should read like this:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
```

Comment: But as I wrote in my edit, it seems to work with versions < 2.7.0